# Moving the li item to the top of the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, material-ui

I have a collapsible material ui, where I want to make sure that whenever an item is clicked it should stay on top.

For example, the default is First, Second, Third. When the user clicks to expand second, it should be moved to top with expanded second as the list look like

First (expanded)

Second

Third

---

Second (expanded)

First

Third

---

If the third is clicked, then the list should display as

Third (expanded)

First

Second

---

```
  <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: you should add your javascript  code that you have worked on so far or you will get downvoted

Comment: What is the specific problem and question? Whatever library you are using for the accordion should have event hooks also. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use the [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function but it seems that the index changes every time we use [`prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) a `li` element. So I thought about fixing this index for every `li`, to do that I affect and `id` property to them automatically.

```
$("li").each(function(index){
  $(this).prop("id",index);
});
```

After that, the only thing we've to do is to prepend the `li` elements depending on the clicked `li` and using the `id` that we added to them. for example, if we click on the second `li` we'll have thisthe following.

```
 if($(this).prop("id")==1){//If it's the second one
   $("ul").prepend($("#2"));
   $("ul").prepend($("#0"));
   $("ul").prepend($("#1"));
  }
```

Finally, here is a code snippet demonstrating all my theory:

```js
$("li").each(function(index){
  $(this).prop("id",index);
});

$("li").on("click",function(){
$(".collapsible-body").hide();
$(this).find(".collapsible-body").show("slow");
 if( $(this).prop("id") == 0 ){//If it's the first one
    $("ul").prepend($("#2"));
    $("ul").prepend($("#1"));
    $("ul").prepend($("#0"));
  }else if($(this).prop("id")==1){//If it's the second one
   $("ul").prepend($("#2"));
   $("ul").prepend($("#0"));
   $("ul").prepend($("#1"));
  }else{//If it's the third one

   $("ul").prepend($("#1"));
   $("ul").prepend($("#0"));
   $("ul").prepend($("#2"));
  }
  
});
```

```css
.collapsible-body{
display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

---

**OPTIMIZATION**

Or you can use this:

```js
$("li").each(function(index){
  $(this).prop("id",index);
});

$("li").on("click",function(){
$(".collapsible-body").hide();
$(this).find(".collapsible-body").show("slow");

for(var i=0;i<$("li").length;i++){
var id="#"+i;
$("ul").append($(id));
}
$("ul").prepend($(this));
});
```

```css
.collapsible-body{
display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```